# Embed YouTube Videos with ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, youtube

I have a bit of an issue. I'm working on a portfolio site and it should automatically list all kinds of content based on URLs that are stored in a `json`. I have this line under the array `videos`.

```
"url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZHwu0uut3k",
"date": "2016-05-11"
```

And I have to use this scheme because I use the links in a different form elsewhere. No problem, I think, and I go to implement a filter.

```
.filter("GetYouTubeID", function ($sce) {
  return function (text) {
      var video_id = text.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];
      return video_id;
  }
})
```

So I go to my HTML and I start with the `ng-repeat`

```
    <div class="media z-depth-1" ng-repeat="video in videos | orderBy: '-date'"  style="padding:20px">
        <div>
     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video.url | GetYouTubeID}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p>Display output for control reasons: {{video.url | GetYouTubeID}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

All this should work, right? However, it doesn't. Why? I can't make sense of this. At all. Please help?

### EDIT #1

After Simon Schüpbach posted his comment, I tried the following, to no avail:

```
.filter("GetYouTubeID", function ($sce) {
  return function (text) {
      var video_id = text.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];
      var ytembed = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
      var complete_id = ytembed + video_id;
      return complete_id;
  }
})
```

I thought that maybe constructing the entire URL in the filter might be smart.

```
 <div class="media z-depth-1" ng-repeat="video in video| orderBy: '-date' | filter: 'video'" style="padding:20px">
                <div>
             <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{video.url | GetYouTubeID}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <p>{{video.url | GetYouTubeID}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This time, my app seems to see that it should embed something, but there's a blank space where the video should be. The control output at the bottom is correct, though.

### Edit #2

I have fidgeted around a bit, following suggestions in this thread. However, nothing worked. If I put a complete embed-URL into the repeating element, the video gets displayed. So the issue is somewhere in the repeat, I concluded.

So I decided to look at Chrome's "inspect element" output. Here's what it gives out:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

You see what's missing? The `src`. So something cuts that out.

The control-URL I display at the bottom always matches a correct Youtube embed URL.

### Edit #3

After @bahadirT suggested it, I tried the following:

In my IndexController:

```
 $scope.getProperURL = function (videoURL) {
        var video_id = videoURL.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];
        return "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id;
    }
```

And in my HTML:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src={{getProperURL(video.url)}} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                    <p>Display output for control reasons: {{video.url | GetYouTubeID}} </p>

                    <p>Function URL: {{getProperURL(video.url)}}</p>
```

Now you'd think that this would work because the line with the Function URL displays the proper URL. However! When I throw ngRepeat at it, Console gives me a number of errors. All are filed under `[$interpolate:interr]`

```
  at Error (native)
    at http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at Function.Ja.interr (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:209:135)
    at H (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:104:156)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:128:176)
    at R.exp (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:105:277)
    at pre (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:79:130)
    at ja (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:80:350)
    at n (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:65:341)
    at g (http://127.0.0.1:58561/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:58:305)
```

Also this one, even though my Content Security Policy is in the Single Page App's Head:

```
jquery.min.js:3The Content Security Policy 'child-src *;' was delivered via a <meta> element outside the document's <head>, which is disallowed. The policy has been ignored.
```

Comment: try `ng-src` instead of `src`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. If you look at my OP, you will see what happened. I basically get a resized Div that pretends that there should be something, but the video isn't displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My code works at this [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bahadirT/japs58q6/1/):

js side [edit]:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
$scope.videos = [
{
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vE0oFFSE7c",
        "date": "2016-05-11"
},
{
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vE0oFFSE7c",
        "date": "2016-05-11"
}
];

});

app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
            var video_id = url.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id);
    };
}]);
```

html side [edit]:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
<div ng-repeat="video in videos | orderBy: '-date'"  style="padding:20px">
<div>
   <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{video.url | trusted}}" 
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>Display output for control reasons: {{video.url | trusted}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I have updated the code and now working with a filter. What I did is to mark the url with "$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()". Found the solution from [here](https://cordovablogsblogs.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/external-resource-not-being-loaded-by-angularjs/).

Comment: Wow! You really went above and beyond. I've tried this and it displays nothing. Not even the element. However! Console gives me this error:

`"jquery.min.js:3 The Content Security Policy 'child-src *;' was delivered via a <meta> element outside the document's <head>, which is disallowed. The policy has been ignored."`

Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: I got your solution to work, but strangely enough, it still doesn't work. I still get the correct URL to be displayed, but when I throw it at the ngRepeat, it fails. I will add an Edit #3 to my OP in a second to show you what I've done. Maybe that helps?

Comment: I have updated my code and it is now working with a filter.

Comment: it's working but facing one issue i.e. getting error in console i.e. *Error: url is undefined* in this line 
` var video_id = url.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some access restrictions.

Add the correct content security policy to allow your usecase.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="child-src *;">
```

**EDIT 1**

I don't know what went wrong in your example but this plunkr works
https://plnkr.co/edit/9FWWsK2Yuf6ivh55w5Uo?p=preview

Comment: That was a very good idea! I have added the exception. However, the ngRepeated videos still don't work. However, if I just copypaste an embed code from YouTube, it works perfectly fine. So the error is somewhere in the ngRepeat now.

Comment: Whats about the content inside the `<p>` tag? Does the path match?

Comment: The path does match. However, I have discovered that on the site I create using the ngRepeated elements do create iframes, but there's no src included. See Edit #2 in my OP. So what would cause my browser to just ignore part of the code? The same code that is displayed one line below in raw form and two lines below in a non-angulared version?

Answer (score 0):

```html
app.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
 return function(url) {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
 };
}]);
and use filter in ng-repeat its working
<iframe ng-src="{{x.url | trusted}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your code. For more info, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.